# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in angularjs production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

In my angularjs application im trying to get some information, in my case longtude and latitude from a rest service online, but is giving me a error of

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://iatageo.com/getLatLng/OPO. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://iatageo.com/getLatLng/OPO","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

My snipped code is:

```
$scope.originAirport = 'OPO';
  $http.get('http://iatageo.com/getLatLng/'+$scope.originAirport).then(function(response){
        $scope.originLatLong = response.data;
    });
```

At first i thougth that was because i was running locally, but after lauching in production i had same issue.
Im using angularjs 1.6*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the API isn't allowing CORS so try to work around it by making your own server that will get the information from the API then pass it to your server.

Again, the API isn't allowing CORS `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://iatageo.com/getLatLng/BSB. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

If you're familiar with NodeJS Express you can use this script below

```
const App = require('express')();
const CORS = require('cors');
const RP  = require('request-promise');

const PORT = 3000;

const BASEURL = 'http://iatageo.com/getLatLng/';

App.use(CORS());

App.get('/getLatLng/:airport', function(request, response) {
    const airportCode = request.params.airport;
    const URL = BASEURL + airportCode;
    RP({ url: URL, json: true }).then(function(data) {
        response.json(data);
    });
});

App.listen(PORT, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('listening to port:', PORT);
});
```

Comment: I already tried it put the app in production and having same issue, is in shared hosting, is it the same?

Comment: Putting it in production isn't going to help. You can contact the developers of the api to let them know that they're not allowing CORS (cross origin resource sharing)
My answer to your problem is to setup a proxy/forwarding server. I will make a edit to my answer with a nodeJS app script